# Instantiating an Object after Destroying in UNITY JAVASCRIPT

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, destroy, unityscript

Destroy Command:

```
var destroyTime : int; // This is the time in seconds
function Start(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(destroyTime);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

I want to destroy an object then create again another object 
can you give me the code of it in unity I have only the 
destroy command

this code destroy the object after a particular time I want 
to respawn my particular object on that position again

Comment: Better performance is setting visibility on/off instead of destroying an creating objects again. Sometimes you need implement something like `init()` method where all attributes reset to default.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-use your object afterwards, then the best thing to do is not destroy it, but disable it.

```
var destroyTime : int; // This is the time in seconds
function Start(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(destroyTime);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Then, you can re-enable it again. But, when you do that and want to keep the "destroy after xx seconds when spawn it, you have to change your function to the "OnEnable" event, because the object was already started. Like this:

```
var destroyTime : int; // This is the time in seconds
function OnEnable(){
    yield WaitForSeconds(destroyTime);
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

PS: I am pretty sure you already have a script attached to some game object which spawns gameObjects, because it will be necessary to do the spwawn/destroy logic. I hope that helps.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your response but I'm having a hard time coding the respawn codes . Can you teach how to do it?? Big thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't work :( my goal is make the cube hide for seconds and appear it again for seconds.

Comment: So, what you want specifically is a traffic light logic?

Comment: It's okay now sir thanks for your responses and hospitality :) I appreciate it

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the questions as answered?